# Is there a way to make area affected by light completely white despite object color in Unity?

Tags: unity, lighting

I have a 3D object that is affected with a directional light with a cookie texture (might be irrelevant). This object has a specific color lets say blue for the example. I would like the area affected by light to be completely whit and not blend with object color. I made a simple sketch of what exactly I want and I am not sure if this is possible at all. [image]

Comment: Should all objects in your game behave this way, or just some special objects, while other objects reflect light normally? And which rendering pipeline are you using? (Built in, Universal, or High Definition)

Comment: It is URP, there is actually only one object it is mostly UI stuff and this object is rendered on render texture.

Comment: I see two approches. First one would be to use a shader that doesn't blend material color with light color. Second one would be to put your object in a specific layer and add a new very bright directional light targetting this layer only.

Comment: Is there a default material that does this or would I need to create a custom shader?